I can't modify the contents of the labels in my meta forest plot
I am using the meta package in R to do a meta analysis.
Problem: I can't modify the labels on the left and right side of the forest plot anymore. The plot only responds to modifications of "studlab", which is created in the meta_analysis object with metagen and is hidden under the yellow box. Setting leftlabs or rightlabs to NULL does not delete the content of leftlabs (TE and SE[]), see picture.
library("meta")

# Sample data
data <- data.frame(
  Study = c("Study 1", "Study 2", "Study 3"),
  Treatment_A_Mean = c(2.5, 3.0, 2.8),
  Treatment_B_Mean = c(2.0, 2.8, 2.5),
  Treatment_A_SD = c(0.5, 0.4, 0.6),
  Treatment_B_SD = c(0.6, 0.5, 0.7),
  n_A = c(30, 25, 28),
  n_B = c(32, 27, 29)
)

# Calculate Cohen's d and its variance for each study
data$Cohens_d <- (data$Treatment_A_Mean - data$Treatment_B_Mean) / sqrt((data$Treatment_A_SD^2 + data$Treatment_B_SD^2) / 2)
data$Variance_d <- (data$Treatment_A_SD^2 / data$n_A + data$Treatment_B_SD^2 / data$n_B) / ((data$n_A + data$n_B) / 2)

# Perform meta-analysis for continuous data using Cohen's d
meta_analysis <- metagen(
  TE = data$Cohens_d,
  seTE = sqrt(data$Variance_d),
  studlab = data$Study,
  comb.fixed = FALSE,
  comb.random = TRUE,
  method.tau = "REML"
)

# Print summary of the meta-analysis
summary(meta_analysis)

# Create a forest plot
meta::forest(meta_analysis,
             xlim = c(-3.5, 1), # Adjusted x-axis limits
             leftlabs = data$Study,  # Display study names on the left side
             rightlabs = c("TE", "95% CI"),  # Labels on the right side
             col.diamond = "purple", # Color of the diamond for summary effect
             col.diamond.lines = "purple", # Color of the lines for summary effect
             col.predict = "red", # Color of the prediction interval
             col.square = "black", # Color of the squares for individual studies
             col.square.lines = "black", # Color of the lines for individual studies
             col.inside = "black", # Color of the inside labels
             col.by = "black", # Color of the by-group labels
             print.byvar = FALSE, # Do not print the by-group variable
             print.tau2 = FALSE, # Do not print the tau²
             backtransf = FALSE # Back-transform the effect size if log-transformed
)




I'm using the latest R studio and all updated package version, all on MacOS.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

It's easier to help you if you include a simple reproducible example with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Thank you for your input. Just learned about MRE! I now made added the MRE. The problem is reproducible. Still, the numbers in the left (Treatment effect, SE of Treatment Effect) and right lab (TE, CI, Weight) are not modifiable in the meta::forest code.

I am so dumb ... so sorry for wasting your time. Just read the documentation by the Package creator. Solution is: Change the "leftcols" inputs, which specifies which columns are displayed on the left side of the plot.
